# Angular 2: i18n bootstrap tooltip title

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-i18n

How to i18n a bootstrap tooltip title

`<i data-toggle="tooltip" title="words to be translated">hover here</i>`

I have tried to put an i18n text mark but can't find the text to be translated in the .xlf file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#add-i18n-translation-attributes)

You can define what are the attributes to be binded i18n-x :

```
<i data-toggle="tooltip" i18n-title title="words to be translated">hover here</i>
```